# Can't create/display php images - GD Image corrupt or truncated

Tags: php, image, gd, broken-image

I'm having a problem and i'd like some help please.
I have made a script for creating an image with PHP using GD library, but the problem is when i preview it on the Firefox it shows me an error in Firebug: "Image corrupt or truncated:localhost/my_scripts/images.php". **NOTE**: this is not an error displayed from PHP, it seems more like an error comming from the browser.

I have checked my code for syntaxes many times, i have also tried out and other gd functions, like imagegif, imagettftext etc etc but didn't have any effect. Here's my code:

```
//$image = @imagecreate(200, 20)or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$image = imagecreate(200, 20);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
imagestring($image,5,5,1,"This is a Test",$foreground);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

GD library is enabled i've already checked that in phpinfo(), and I have also tried to preview it and on Chrome and looks the same. Any ideas what i might doing wrong or why happens this? and how can i fix this error??

Comment: Comment out the `header` call and `imagejpeg`, then visit the script.  Do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: if I comment out the header function shows strange symbolslike these:

����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�

Comment: That is why you need to comment out `imagejpeg` as well.  The most common cause of browsers whining about corrupted images is due to PHP warnings or notices being emitted with the image data.  Eliminate the header and the image data, and warnings and notices may well appear.

Comment: Those strange characters are the raw image data

Comment: these characters appear if you comment out the header(). it isn't an error, you just use the header to tell the browser that this file is gonna be an image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found something about this error and finally i figured out what was going on, so here is the solution to the problem:

Make sure that PHP code is the only thing on the page. No HTML, no spaces before or after the PHP code, etc, the only thing it should send to the browser should be the image data. If that still doesn't work then make sure that saving the PHP script in a format that does not include the UTF BOM and this should fix it.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, Lykos. Setting the coding to Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) made it work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code to `UTF-8 without BOM` and worked to me! Thanks Lykos.